# How to use IO String function in Xmonad key bindings?

Tags: haskell, monads, xmonad

I've configured Xmonad to launch *dmenu_path*:

```
((myModMask, xK_p), spawn (sHOME ++ "/.xmonad/dmenu_path"))
```

*spawn* runs the script, *dmenu_path* runs *dmenu* and exec the command.

**~/.xmonad/dmenu_path**:

```
eval "exec $(dmenu)"
```

I'd like to replace the script with a haskell function. I've write a simple 'IO String' function (`fDmenuPath :: IO String`) in **~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs**. I'd like to do something like:

```
((myModMask, xK_p), spawn (fDmenuPath))
```

Running `xmonad --recompile` shows this error:

```
xmonad.hs:130:35
    Couldn't match type `IO String' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: IO String
....
```

I'm newbie with haskell. I don't know how to use the function to retrieve the result string, and pass it to *spawn*.

Any Suggestion, please?

This is the code for **fDmenuPath**:

```
pdmpCmd1 p = proc "echo" [p]
pdmpCmd2 = proc "tr" [":","\\n"]
pdmpCmd3 = proc "uniq" []
pdmpCmd4 = proc "sed" ["s|$|/|"]
pdmpCmd5 = proc "xargs" ["ls","-lu","--time-style=+%s"]
pdmpCmd6 = proc "awk" ["/^(-|l)/ { print $6, $7 }"]
pdmpCmd7 = proc "sort" ["-rn"]
pdmpCmd8 = proc "cut" ["-d ","-f","2"]
pdmpCmd9 = proc "dmenu" ["-fn","-*-terminus-*-r-normal-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*","-nb","#000000","-nf","#839496","-sb","#859900"]

fDmenuPath :: IO String
fDmenuPath = do
    sPATH <- getEnv "PATH"
    (_, Just ho1, _, hp1) <- createProcess (pdmpCmd1 sPATH)
                    { std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho2, _, hp2) <- createProcess pdmpCmd2
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho1 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho3, _, hp3) <- createProcess pdmpCmd3
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho2 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho4, _, hp4) <- createProcess pdmpCmd4
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho3 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho5, _, hp5) <- createProcess pdmpCmd5
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho4 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho6, _, hp6) <- createProcess pdmpCmd6
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho5 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho7, _, hp7) <- createProcess pdmpCmd7
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho6 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho8, _, hp8) <- createProcess pdmpCmd8
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho7 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    (_, Just ho9, _, hp9) <- createProcess pdmpCmd9
                    { std_in = UseHandle ho8 ,
                      std_out = CreatePipe }
    sOut <- hGetContents ho9
    ec1 <- waitForProcess hp1
    ec2 <- waitForProcess hp2
    ec3 <- waitForProcess hp3
    ec4 <- waitForProcess hp4
    ec5 <- waitForProcess hp5
    ec6 <- waitForProcess hp6
    ec7 <- waitForProcess hp7
    ec8 <- waitForProcess hp8
    ec9 <- waitForProcess hp9
    return $ sOut
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't use xmonad, but can you give more context for `((myModMask, xK_p), spawn (fDmenuPath))` ? What's its supposed result type?

Comment: Most of the stuff you're doing in `fDmenuPath` really shouldn't be done by spawning processes -- doing it within Haskell will give much better performance. You can probably steal some code from [yeganesh](http://dmwit.com/yeganesh/) if all you're after is a listing of programs in your path. e.g. see `lsx` in [main.hs](http://dmwit.com/yeganesh/main.hs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two pieces you're looking for are

```
liftIO :: IO a -> X a
(>>=) :: X a -> (a -> X b) -> X b
```

Combining them,

```
liftIO fDmenuPath >>= spawn :: X ()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your sample builds ok. It calls the function, runs dmenu to select a command and it should work, but it seems that `fDmenuPath` returns nothing running in Xmonad. The function, in combination (_>>=_) with `XMonad.Util.Dzen.dzenConfig` (stripping new lines from text), doesn't show the **dzen** window with the choosen text. I've tested the function in a simple haskell file (`fDmenuPath >>= putStr`) and it works (it runs dmenu).

Comment: @user3303204 Perhaps you can open a new question with the details of your new problem. It's a bit hard to follow exactly what you're doing, what you're expecting to happen, and what happens instead when you compress it hard enough to fit in a comment.